# “Did” vs. “had done”

Tags: tense, conditional-constructions, verb-forms

Are both these constructions possible to mean the same thing?

> 1. If I told you how I **did** it, it wouldn't be a surprise.
> 2. If I told you how I **had done** it, it wouldn't be a surprise.

Answer (score 6):

SHORT ANSWER:
No. The second sentence is ungrammatical.

LONGER ANSWER:
The past forms you employ, *told* in the *condition* or *IF* clause and *would* in the *consequence* or *THEN* clause, do not signify past tense; they signify *unreal* mode. These two clauses are both cast in the non-past tense. The Reference Time of these sentences—the time you are speaking about—is therefore **non-past**, present+future, “from now on”. The simple past form *did* properly refers the pastness of what you did to that “present” Reference Time: it happened “before now”.

A past perfect like *had done*, however, must be related to a **past** Reference Time: it distinguishes an event as having taken place “before **then**”, not “before now”. In your second sentence the past perfect has no past time to which it may be related; the sentence is therefore ungrammatical.

What you may say is

> If I told you how I **have done** it, it wouldn't be a surprise.

There is however no particular reason I can think of why you should use a perfect there: you are speaking of a past event, not a present state, so the simple past *did* is preferred.